# Synchronize simulation time with real time

Tags: unity-game-engine, time, synchronization, simulation

I'm doing a simulation. It must be consistent from machine to machine, so I'm not using `Time.deltaTime`, but using a fixed value to represent the frame duration (say 0.002s).

The problem is: though the simulation is consistent, irregularities in the durations of the frames of the game make it look like in a long frame it moves X and in a short frame it also moves X, making it look wierd from time to time.

The question: is there a way to synchronize real time with simulation time without losing simulation precision?

Comment: Is there any way you could show some code? I'd have to see how exactly you're doing your calculations. I would think that would want to use Time.deltaTime so that you would not have any scenario where thinks move the same regardless of the frame duration.

Comment: I don't think the code will be useful for you, I'll give you an example to explain why: Suppose a ball will collide with a wall. If I use `Time.deltaTime`, in 3 different executions, I may have 3 different collision times which will cause mismatch in the evaluations of the ball position before the collision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time.deltatime tells us how much time has passed since the last frame.

From Unity [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html):

> This property provides the time between the current and previous frame.

If you wait
a fixed time between frames, the framerate will affect your simulation time.

If you want to do something in the game world every 1 second in the real world, you need to use Time.deltatime. You keep track of how much time has passed by adding Time.deltatime to a variable and check if it is equal to or more than wanted time.

```
private float timer = 0.0f;
private float waitTime = 1.0f;

void Update() {
    timer += Time.deltatime;
    if (timer >= waitTime) {
        timer = 0.0f;
        doStuff();
    }
}
```

---

Instead of using Time.deltatime you may want to use Unity's [Fixedupdate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html).
You use it just like you'd use Update() but instead of firing every frame, it fires it
on a fixed interval. Default is 0.02s and you can change it from Edit > Settings > Time > Fixed Timestep. This is used for physics calculations.

I hope this answered your question and/or helped you with your problem. If there is something I missed let me know and I'll try to give a better answer.

Comment: Just an FYI, be careful with putting questions in your answers. I understand you can't comment yet, but when you can, you should put any questions into a comment on the original post first. I was flagged and down-voted for framing an answer like this before. Ridiculous, I know, but I figured I would pass the info along.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I edited my answer!

Comment: This answer is very interesting. I knew `FixedUpdate` was used for physics, but I didn't know it was called at fixed intervals. This is exactly the consistency I needed.